# Отследить заполнение поля одними пробелами

Tags: html, html5

Как можно в атрибуте `pattern` запретить ввод только пробелов в поле?

Comment: \s – все пробелы и пропуски строк

Comment: `pattern=".*\S+.*"` ?

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, это помогло.